# How do you trigger autocomplete "select" event manually in jQueryUI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jQueryUI autocomplete, and I have a function mapped to the select event, e.g.:

```
$("#someId").autocomplete({
    source: someData,
    select: function (event, ui) { ... },
    focus: function (event, ui) { ... }
});
```

I have a special case: The user has focused on an item in the autocomplete drop-down (but not selected it) and I need to trigger the select event manually from a different function. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

```
$(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._trigger('select', 'autocompleteselect', {item:{value:$(this).val()}});
```

Comment: nice one, is there any better solution?

Comment: Excellent! this is the only solution that actually trigger the event and not just mimics a user interaction with the UI.

Comment: This is better than the selected answer because it passes in the important "ui" data

Comment: Error: Unable to get property '_trigger' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @JosephNorris Instead, try... `$(this).data('autocomplete')._trigger('select', 'autocompleteselect', {item:{value:$(this).val()}});`

Comment: I needed to change 'value' to 'id' else `ui.item.id` is undefined.

Comment: If you get the same problem as Joseph Norris (Cannot read property '_trigger' of undefined), try `console.log($(this).data());`. In my case it was 'customTableAutocomplete'

Comment: `console.log($(this).data());` gives undefined

Answer (score 10):

You could do:

```
$("#someId").trigger("autocompleteselect");
```

Comment: It's because this will only work if events are bound with `$().on('autocompleteselect')` and not when bound on construction with `$().autocomplete({select:function() {}})`. Use `$().data('autocomplete')._trigger()` then

Comment: can you explain more how to select an option in select?

Answer (score 7):

You can do it the way the jQuery team does it in their unit tests - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15466735/1016885) answer

Answer (score 6):

Simply call following function

`setAutocomplete("#txt_User_Name","rohit");`

```
function setAutocomplete(autocompleteId,valuetoset)
    {
        $(autocompleteId).val(valuetoset);
        $(autocompleteId).autocomplete("search", valuetoset);
        var list = $(autocompleteId).autocomplete("widget");
        $(list[0].children[0]).click();
    }
```

Comment: I had to add a timeout to this as my search wasn't finished in time (is an ajax call)

Answer (score 3):

1 line solution

```
$('.ui-menu-item .ui-corner-all:contains(\"123")').autocomplete({autoFocus:true}).mouseenter().click()
```

Comment: Using `.mouseenter().click()` helped me select an item from the results correctly

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#someId').data('uiAutocomplete')._trigger('select');
```

Comment: was really stuck with this, thanks a lot, I used it to trigger the change, like this $('#someId').data('uiAutocomplete')._trigger('change');

Answer (score 3):

If we want to trigger search of something particularly:

```
$('#search-term').autocomplete('search', 'searching term');
```

or just

```
$('#search-term').autocomplete('search');

$('#search-term').autocomplete({
    ...
    minLength: 0, // with this setting
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From outside:

```
$($('#someId').data('autocomplete').menu.active).find('a').trigger('click');
```

An example how to setup select triggering at pressing of horizontal arrows keys from inside of "open" autocomplete event:

```
$('#someId').autocomplete({
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).keydown(function(e){
            /* horizontal keys */
            if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39) {
               $($(this).data('autocomplete').menu.active).find('a').trigger('click');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Unfortunately that nice way how to solve this marked as "success" did not work at my app in chromium 140.0.835.200

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to go through a bunch of rigmarole to call select. This is how I call select from my own extended version of autocomplete.

```
$(this).data('ui-autocomplete').options.select(event, ui);
```

where I use this

```
/**
 * The jQuery UI plugin autocomplete
 */
$.widget( "ui.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
   options: {
      close: function( event, ui ) {
         if (typeof event.currentTarget == 'undefined') {
            $(this).val("");
            $(this).data('ui-autocomplete').options.select(event, ui);
         }
      }
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found very simple way to make it work. 
Answers above did not work for me.

My input definition:

```
<div class="search_box">
<input type="text" class="inp disabled" id="search-user-id" placeholder="Search by user name or email" />
</div>
```

The autocomplete definition:

```
$('#search-user-id').autocomplete({
    minChars: 3,
    paramName: 'searchTerm',
    deferRequestBy: 200, // This is to avoid js error on fast typing
    serviceUrl: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/settings/reset/psw/query',
    type: 'POST',
    onSelect : function(suggestion) {
        showUserData(suggestion.dto);
    }, 
    onSearchError: function (query, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('.cev-error-fields.reset-password').find('.error_msg').text(errorThrown).show().fadeOut(7000);
    }
});
```

Trigger it:
I am triggering from an ajax defined in other page, 
I do not put the ajax here for simplicity. 
Inside the ajax response I just trigger it this way:

```
        $('#search-user-id').val(username);
        $('#search-user-id').focus();
```

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this thread as I was seeking a way to prefill a bunch of jquery ui autocomplete fields in a form where users can modify an already submitted one.

First, I have to load the form, with some inputs using autocomplete.

Problem 1 : I created a php function able to call a premade autocomplete input, specifying some things like the input class, id, name... and value(s). I can also pass the name of a JS custom function to trigger (with the selected item's ID as a parameter), depending on the form and type of data... So I can't just "print" the prefilled input when loading the form because the custom function (and other actions specified in the built-in select: function( event, ui ) { ... } won't fire.
I really need to mimic a search-->click action.

Problem 2 : the source comes from an ajax call performing a search from the string entered in the input. It then shows strings as items... but I want the real input to be the IDs of those sources. To do so, the select: event creates a hidden input with the ID of the clicked item, checks if it was already selected (I can select multiple elements from one autocomplete input..), etc. It has to be triggered.
I really need to mimic a search-->click action.

Problem 3 : Since the source comes from an ajax call, I would have to make all these calls to prefill the form, which is a very bad way of populating a form (for various reasons).
I can't really mimic the search-->click action.

Solution
I simply created a second (hidden) autocomplete input for each "real ones", for which the initialisation $(id).autocomplete(...) performs the same actions (upon select), but is populated with static source i drew directly from the DB with the already saved input. Then, I simply mimic the search-->click in this dummy input, which draws the good inputs with the IDs I want to save...

```
foreach (values to prefill..) {
 $("#'.$mot_cle.'_input_autocomplete_prefill").val("'.$valeur_finale_unique['value'].'");
 $("#'.$mot_cle.'_input_autocomplete_prefill").autocomplete("search", "'.$valeur_finale_unique['value'].'");
 var list = $("#'.$mot_cle.'_input_autocomplete_prefill").autocomplete("widget");
 $(list[0].children[0]).click();
}
```

It's quite complicated. But in the end, everytime I want to show an autocomplete input in my pages, I only have to call the php function which wraps it up ;)
And it's lightning fast, and don't mess with the input IDs\Names for the entire forms managing...

There is a lot going on backend, but in the end, it looks like this, when I enter this :

```
<div class="marge">
 <span class="texte_gras">Demandeur(s)</span><br>
 '.formulaire_autocomplete("demandeurs","pdrh_formulaire_ajouter_cible_valeurs","1","usager",$valeur_demandeur,"").'
</div>
```

*PHP function formulaire_autocomplete($keyword(used for input name),$class(used for jquery serialize when submitting form),$multi(possibility to input more than one choice),$type(which DB table to search: users, courses, etc..),$value(IDs to prefill in the form for this input, if it is an already submitted form), $function(if I want to trigger a custom JS function when select:))*

I get this :

```
<div class="marge">
                        <span class="texte_gras">Demandeur(s)</span><br>
                            <input style="width: 90%;" class="pdrh_formulaire_ajouter_cible_valeurs ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" name="demandeurs[]" id="demandeurs_input_autocomplete" value="" autocomplete="off">  <input style="width: 90%; display: none;" class="pdrh_formulaire_ajouter_cible_valeurs ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" name="demandeurs_prefill[]" id="demandeurs_input_autocomplete_prefill" value="" autocomplete="off">   <div id="demandeurs_boite_autocomplete_selection" style="width: 100%;"><div style="width: 100%;" id="demandeurs_auto_ID_25434"><div class="petite_marge"><input style="width: 80%;" class="pdrh_formulaire_ajouter_cible_valeurs" type="hidden" name="demandeurs_auto_ID[]" id="demandeurs_input_autocomplete_auto_id_25434" value="25434"><span class="petit_texte texte_gras">STEPHANIE (41263)</span><div class="bouton_transparent" onclick="effacer_div('demandeurs_auto_ID_25434')"><div class="petite_marge"><img src="./images/vide.png" style="width: 1em;"><img src="./images/effacer.png" style="width: 1em;"></div></div></div></div><div style="width: 100%;" id="demandeurs_auto_ID_18760"><div class="petite_marge"><input style="width: 80%;" class="pdrh_formulaire_ajouter_cible_valeurs" type="hidden" name="demandeurs_auto_ID[]" id="demandeurs_input_autocomplete_auto_id_18760" value="18760"><span class="petit_texte texte_gras">MARIE (23673)</span><div class="bouton_transparent" onclick="effacer_div('demandeurs_auto_ID_18760')"><div class="petite_marge"><img src="./images/vide.png" style="width: 1em;"><img src="./images/effacer.png" style="width: 1em;"></div></div></div></div></div><script>
                    $("#demandeurs_input_autocomplete").autocomplete({
                        source: function (request, response) {
                            requete_ajax = $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: 'fonctions.php',
                                data: 'recherche_autocomplete=usager&chaine='+request.term,
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function(data) {
                                    ajax_en_cours = 0; console.log("Ajax terminé");
                                    // var resultat = JSON.parse(data.choix);
                                    var tableau_resultat = Object.values(data.choix);
                                    response(tableau_resultat);
                                    console.log(tableau_resultat);
                                },
                                error: function(e) {
                                    ajax_en_cours = 0; console.log("Ajax terminé");
                                    console.log('Erreur | demandeurs recherche autocomplete');
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        minLength: 3,
                        select: function( event, ui ) {
                            $("#demandeurs_input_autocomplete_auto_id").val(ui.item.ID);
                                var contenu_selection = $("#demandeurs_boite_autocomplete_selection").html();
                            $("#demandeurs_boite_autocomplete_selection").html(contenu_selection+"<div style=\"width: 100%;\" id=\"demandeurs_auto_ID_"+ui.item.ID+"\"><div class=\"petite_marge\"><input style=\"width: 80%;\" class=\"pdrh_formulaire_ajouter_cible_valeurs\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"demandeurs_auto_ID[]\" id=\"demandeurs_input_autocomplete_auto_id_"+ui.item.ID+"\" value=\""+ui.item.ID+"\"><span class=\"petit_texte texte_gras\">"+ui.item.value+"</span><div class=\"bouton_transparent\" onclick=\"effacer_div('demandeurs_auto_ID_"+ui.item.ID+"')\"><div class=\"petite_marge\"><img src=\"./images/vide.png\" style=\"width: 1em;\"><img src=\"./images/effacer.png\" style=\"width: 1em;\"></div></div></div></div>");
                            $("#demandeurs_input_autocomplete").val(" ");
                            
                        }
                    });
                        var valeurs_prefill = [{value: "STEPHANIE  (41263)", ID: "25434"},{value: "MARIE (23673)", ID: "18760"}];
                        $("#demandeurs_input_autocomplete_prefill").autocomplete({
                            source: valeurs_prefill,
                            minLength: 3,
                            select: function( event, ui ) {
                                $("#demandeurs_input_autocomplete_auto_id").val(ui.item.ID);
                                    var contenu_selection = $("#demandeurs_boite_autocomplete_selection").html();
                            $("#demandeurs_boite_autocomplete_selection").html(contenu_selection+"<div style=\"width: 100%;\" id=\"demandeurs_auto_ID_"+ui.item.ID+"\"><div class=\"petite_marge\"><input style=\"width: 80%;\" class=\"pdrh_formulaire_ajouter_cible_valeurs\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"demandeurs_auto_ID[]\" id=\"demandeurs_input_autocomplete_auto_id_"+ui.item.ID+"\" value=\""+ui.item.ID+"\"><span class=\"petit_texte texte_gras\">"+ui.item.value+"</span><div class=\"bouton_transparent\" onclick=\"effacer_div('demandeurs_auto_ID_"+ui.item.ID+"')\"><div class=\"petite_marge\"><img src=\"./images/vide.png\" style=\"width: 1em;\"><img src=\"./images/effacer.png\" style=\"width: 1em;\"></div></div></div></div>");
                            $("#demandeurs_input_autocomplete").val(" ");
                                
                            }
                        });
                            $("#demandeurs_input_autocomplete_prefill").val("STEPHANIE (41263)");
                            $("#demandeurs_input_autocomplete_prefill").autocomplete("search", "STEPHANIE (41263)");
                            
                                var list = $("#demandeurs_input_autocomplete_prefill").autocomplete("widget");
                                $(list[0].children[0]).click();
                            
                            
                        
                            $("#demandeurs_input_autocomplete_prefill").val("MARIE (23673)");
                            $("#demandeurs_input_autocomplete_prefill").autocomplete("search", "MARIE (23673)");
                            
                                var list = $("#demandeurs_input_autocomplete_prefill").autocomplete("widget");
                                $(list[0].children[0]).click();
                            
                            
                            </script>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to [temuri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17220097/5211833), if you want to see the label and not the value, you probably need to add it as well in the code:

```
$(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._trigger('select', 'autocompleteselect', {item:{value: 'theValYouWant', label: 'labelShownInTheAutocomplete'}});
```

Comment: You know about the commenting privilege which you do not have, so well that you can even put it into words. You are aware of the rule https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (an answer) for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed yet to do.

Comment: I do not see how your contribution answers the question at the top of this page. But if you can demonstrate that the use of the label is most likely part of it (though not mentioned as far as I can tell), then you can turn this comment into an answer of your own. By phrasing e.g. "Since using the label is probably part of the goal here (because ....), here is how to add that needed feature, based on the existing answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17220097/7733418 . ...."