# Jquery-autocomplete: makes the tab key select the first item if no item is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The **goal** of this question is: **by using jquery-autocomplete, makes the <kbd>tab</kbd> key able to select the first item if no item is selected.**

The code I have implemented (1) works but  I have some doubts and I would like to clarify them or, if it is possible, improve/change the code (1) in order to achieve my goal.

My doubts are:

I am triggering ENTER too early: the event dispatching is asynchronous (the different listeners are called synchronously, but it is asynchronous of the trigger), so I may trigger it before the listener handled DONE).
Thus, I am still using the same object for both events here, so I may have nasty side effects (if I prevent the default during the first dispatching, it will be prevented for the second one too as it is the same object for instance).

Any suggestion/comment?

P.S.:

1. Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/uymYJ/31/.
2. This question is related to this one [How to avoid to modify the event object in this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041811/how-to-avoid-to-modify-the-event-object-in-this-situation/12050471#12050471).

---

(1)

```
$("#box").keydown(function(event){
    var newEvent = $.Event('keydown', {
        keyCode: event.keyCode
    });

    if (newEvent.keyCode !== $.ui.keyCode.TAB) {
        return;
    }

    newEvent.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.DOWN;
    $(this).trigger(newEvent);

    newEvent.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.ENTER;
    $(this).trigger(newEvent);
});
```

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you what is `$.Event`? I found nothing in jQuery API, but `console.log($.Event)` outputs `function`. Can you provide a link to the docs?

Comment: @caligula, thanks for your comment. Here is the link http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/. In my code: `jQuery.Event` is equal to `$.Event`

Comment: Just to clarify - you *only* want the tab key select the first item, meaning you want to disable the up+down arrows?

Comment: @Chazbot I want to keep the same behaviour and add the following: `tab key select the first item if no item is selected`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery autocomplete manual input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599621/jquery-autocomplete-manual-input) (altough no answer)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need something like this:

```
$("#box").keydown(function(event){
    var newEvent = $.Event('keydown', {
        keyCode: event.keyCode
    });

    if (newEvent.keyCode !== $.ui.keyCode.TAB) {
        return;
    }

    if (newEvent.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.TAB) {
        // custom logic for tab
        newEvent.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.DOWN;
        $(this).trigger(newEvent);
        return false;
    }

    // ...
});
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answwer. Can you explain the reason of your choise? thanks.

Comment: I think you need to make some custom TAB press behavior. Becaus default one is not proper for you task.