# jQuery Auto-complete - Force Selection/Testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, integration-testing, jquery-autocomplete

I have a simpe jQuery autocomplete input box with the ID 'medID'

```
$('#medID').val("Par").focus().keydown();
```

I use the code above to put a value in the box, trigger focus and then key down to search.

It returns between 1-5 values.

How do i get it automaticly select one of the suggested values?

I have tried:

```
$('#medID').children()[0].focus().click();
```

and

```
$('#medID').children().focus().click();
```

But the suggested auto complete values are direct chilren of the input box?

This is so i can test this part of my system without the need of a user.

Comment: Did you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/u7KAx/39/)?

Comment: Yes but i cant get that working with a combo box :(

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242669/jquery-autocomplete-manually-select-first-searched-item-and-bind-click?lq=1) (2nd answer, first comment) might be of some help

Comment: Im lookin there the now, its like my combobox input just doesnt take focus

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Yea give me a few mins

Comment: Would you be able to make a simple one with a combo box? As i am finding it hard to extract this information esp from senesitve data

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain, but I think browsers prohibit this. Your request might turn out to be impossible.

If it were possible, a malicious script could gain access to data that users had previously typed into `input` fields, e.g. credit card numbers or email addresses, using a script just like the one you outlined.  This would be a pretty bad security hole.

Sorry about that.  Perhaps you could get away with just looping through the input values your want to test and calling `$('#medID').val(testValueHere)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery UI team do something similar for their own [unit tests for autocomplete](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/tests/unit/autocomplete/autocomplete_core.js). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15466735/1016885) for more details.