# Why can't my Capybara/Poltergeist test select from a jQuery autocomplete field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, jquery-autocomplete, poltergeist

---

UPDATE: I have fixed this problem after lots of painstaking work on my own. I am happy to be a resource to anybody needing a hand with this. Here is a gist of my [working setup.](https://gist.github.com/HuckyDucky/10219649)

---

I have tried every solution I could find Google and SO. Here are some different things I have tried:

```
page.execute_script %Q{$('#{selector}').val('#{value}').trigger('keydown')}
```

and

```
fill_in field, with: options[:with]
page.execute_script %Q{ $('##{field}').trigger('focus') }
page.execute_script %Q{ $('##{field}').trigger('keydown') }
```

This is what fails:

```
page.should have_selector('ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a')
```

But it's definitely there when I look at it in Firebug and test it in the browser.

Here are all of the details, including a restatement of those above. Remember, the autocomplete field works fine in the browser.

`listing_integration_spec.rb`

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "Listing Integration" do

  let!(:user) { login_user }

  it "lets a user add information listing", js: true do
    listing = create(:listing, user: user)
    click_link('Additional Information')
    click_link('Create')
    fill_autocomplete('listings_search', with: listing.item_id)
  end

end
```

`spec/support/feature_helper.rb`

```
def fill_autocomplete(field, options = {})
  fill_in field, with: options[:with]
  page.execute_script %Q{ $('##{field}').trigger('focus') }
  page.execute_script %Q{ $('##{field}').trigger('keydown') }
  selector = %Q{ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a:contains('#{options[:with]}')}
  page.should have_selector('ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a')
  page.execute_script %Q{ $("##{selector}").trigger('mouseenter').click() }
end
```

`ERB from view template`

```
<%= simple_fields_for :listings  do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :search, label: "Search by Listing", required: true %>
<% end %>
```

and the Coffeescript:

```
$("#listings_search").autocomplete
  source: (request, response) ->
    options = 
      term: request.term
    $.get "/search_listings", options, (data) ->
      if data.length == 0
        alert "No listings found."
      response data
  minLength: 2
  select: (event, ui) ->
    add_listing_hash = 
      type: "GET"
      url: "/add_listing"
      data: { id: ui.item.id }
      success: () ->
    $.ajax(add_listing_hash)
```

Comment: Can you please post the markup of the page that you're testing, and the complete source code of the test that you're running?

Comment: Did you try debugging the issue in the running poltergeist session?

Comment: I did. It attempts to call the events, but the events are not triggering the autocomplete the way they are supposed to. I wasn't even able to invoke autocomplete directly.

Comment: Have you tried running the spec using `selenium`?  Obviously a longer spec but it's worth a try. Especially AJAX stuff IMHO

Comment: Did you try adding some delay between the different steps ? That's dirty, I know, but that may be way to identify a possible race condition.

Comment: I added "sleep 5" between all of the steps with no improvement. Please note that I have discovered that the "autocomplete" event is indeed being triggered, and is returning one row of data, but that the text box that autocomplete generates with it's results can't be seen. When debugging this behavior in Poltergeist, I find that Poltergeist uses the full length of the ```timeout``` I have it configured with it, then fails to find the ```ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a``` selector. Something is making Poltergeist hang up after autocomplete is initiated.

Comment: Have you tried taking a screenshot in poltergeist at each point to see what poltergeist can see? https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist#taking-screenshots-with-some-extensions

Comment: Have you tried using an array rather than ajax to load the test data?  From what I understand of Capybara it should handle async ok, but it would be worthwhile to try and simplify the problem.

Comment: I'm definitely screenshotting the heck out of the test. The autocomplete "fires" but is struggling to allow clicks on the results box.

Comment: @AKWF would you mind sharing your solution with us? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: I would also like to see the solution.

Comment: Hi guys. Everything had to do with my setup. If your autocomplete is working in the browser, but not in RSpec, here is everything in my setup for you to look at and copy. Hopefully saves you some time. Let me know if anything is missing. https://gist.github.com/HuckyDucky/10219649

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JS drivers are generally meh, they're slow and not single one of them covers 100% of function, and they're often quirky and hard to debug, but I'm sure you've got that figured out by now.

I've got similar piece of code working on rails 3.2, minitest and poltergeist 1.3.0 (an ajaxed dropdown) but it kind of breaks periodically for no good reason (one might say it has a poltergeist? I have already resorted switching that test between selenium and poltergeist a couple times so far), not sure why autocompleter wouldn't work for you but it feels like a bug,

submit issue to https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist (you already have? https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/issues/439), try changing to selenium or webkit, see if it works, you can use a different driver in this one test if it gets you out of the woods (it beats losing days of work over a widget that works).

Comment: There are so many moving parts (what events jQuery uses to trigger an autocomplete, PhantomJS, Capybara configuration) that the answer truly is ```meh```. I got as far as having the results HTML generated but failing the mouseenter click.

Comment: I traced the mouseenter click failure to bad stuff on my part. I also updated all involved gems to the bleeding edge, and I started to see results. The whole thing probably took 48 hours of work to solve. Fortunately it's for my own stuff so no one has to pay except me ;-) As frustrating as this was, I am better for having waded through all the moving parts.

Answer (score 6):

I've found several solutions online, none of which work with current versions of Poltergeist, Capybara, and Autocomplete. But I learned enough from them to make a working helper method, with no sleep calls.

```
def fill_autocomplete(css_id, page, options = {})
  find("#{css_id}").native.send_keys options[:with]
  page.execute_script %{ $('#{css_id}').trigger('focus') }
  page.execute_script %{ $('#{css_id}').trigger('keydown') }
  selector = %{ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item:contains("#{options[:select]}")}
  expect(page).to have_selector('ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item')
  page.execute_script %{ $('#{selector}').trigger('mouseenter').click() }
end
```

Example usage:

```
fill_autocomplete(
  '#contact_filter_company',
  listing_page,
  with:   'acm',
  select: 'Acme'
)
```

I have a `page` argument because I'm using [SitePrism](https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism) - if you're not, you can strip it out.

I'm using this with:

- jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.11.2
- poltergeist 1.5.1
- capybara 2.4.4
- rspec 3.1.0

Comment: What exactly is listing page? The rails helper for the page?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to test my autocompleting text field with Poltergeist without much trouble. The main thing to know about is Poltergeist's `.native.send_keys` method.

Hacking together a summary out of the Cucumber steps where these lines of code actually live in my project:

```
find('#username').native.send_keys "the" # this field autocompletes usernames
wait_until { all('a', text: "the_username").any? }
find('a', text: "the_username").click
```

Then I submit the form and assert the expected results on the following page in the usual way.

`wait_until` ([a reimplementation of a method which was removed from Capybara 2](http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara)) takes a block which returns true when we should stop waiting. It's faster than waiting for 5 seconds or whatever every time.

```
def wait_until(delay = 1)
  seconds_waited = 0
  while ! yield && seconds_waited < Capybara.default_wait_time
    sleep delay
    seconds_waited += 1
  end
  raise "Waited for #{Capybara.default_wait_time} seconds but condition did not become true" unless yield
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you need a mixture of triggering KEYDOWN, but also setting the keycode to DOWN.

e.g.

```
var keyEvent = $.Event("keydown");
keyEvent.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.DOWN;  

$("#autocomplete").val("j");       

$("#autocomplete").trigger(keyEvent);
```

Here is a working jsfiddle example showing an item selected by the autocomplete: http://jsfiddle.net/alexkey/74BST/ I'm not sure why you need to trigger keydown twice, but that's a problem to solve separately (if a problem at all).

However I'm not familiar with the unit testing framework you are using, but I hope the above helps.

Credit goes to [JQuery AutoComplete, manually select first searched item and bind click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242669/jquery-autocomplete-manually-select-first-searched-item-and-bind-click)

I'm using the example code form: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#entry-examples

The autocomplete unit tests that the jquery-ui team uses may come in useful for inspiration: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/tests/unit/autocomplete

Also a reference to the keycode: http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.ui.keyCode/

Comment: I gave this a shot. The autocomplete is being triggered, but Poltergeist is hanging up on the generation of the results HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and no proposed solution could solve it. My tests always failed when trying to find the `ul.ui-autocomplete` element. I finally noticed, that jQuery autocomplete appends the `ul` to the end of the html page and NOT to the input field in question. In my spec, I follow the practice of targeting my forms explicitly by `within my_form do` and doing all the `fill_in`stuff inside this block:

```
within my_form do
  fill_autocomplete …
end
```

Of course this could never find the `ul` attached OUTSIDE this form element. My solution was simple: Use jQuery autocomplete's attribute `appendTo: '#id_of_input_field'` when initializing autocomplete. Now it can find my `ul`and everything works fine.