# how to test / interact with AJAX autocomplete and Capybara / Poltergeist

Tags: ruby, ajax, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I am trying to interact with an external website at: http://is.gd/LtgYEk
I need to be able to fill in the input with id="textOrigen" here is the html

```html
<p>
    <label class="form-label">Departing from:</label>
    <span class="label-field">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" onblur="onblur2('textOrigen');" onfocus="initID('textOrigen');" size="17" id="textOrigen" name="text" maxlength="40" style="position:static;color: #505050;">
        <select style="display:none" onchange="clearValidate(); Origen();" class="validate[dynamic]" id="cmbOrigen" name="cmbOrigen">
            <option value="-1" selected="selected">Origin</option>
        </select>
        <label class="label-error" id="lblerrorOrigen"></label> 
    </span>
</p>
```

I put together a simple ruby script using 'capybara/poltergeist'

I am unable to replicate the browser behavior, which is:
    on click the input field default value is highlighted thus being deleted as you start typing.

I lost track of all different variations I tried, but tried many. I found another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830194/why-cant-my-capybara-poltergeist-test-select-from-a-jquery-autocomplete-field) which seemed somewhat useful but it didn't help

This is the last revision of the method to fill this field:

```
def session.fill_autocomplete(field, options = {})
  execute_script %Q{ $('##{field}').trigger('focus') }
  fill_in field, with: options[:with]
  execute_script %Q{ $('##{field}').trigger('focus') }
  execute_script %Q{ $('##{field}').trigger('keydown') }
  selector = %Q{#output div:contains('#{options[:with]}')}
  execute_script "$(\"#{selector}\").mouseenter().click()"
end
```

As I wrote the script is very simple, the only other relevant bit is when the session is instantiated with:

```
session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after testing in many ways.
The key was to add some delay to allow the auto suggest div to be populated.

Here is the method that worked:

```
def session.fill_city(field, options = {})
  sleep 3
  script = %Q{ $("#{field}").focus().keypress().val("#{options[:with]}") }
  execute_script(script)
  sleep 2
  find('#output').find('div').trigger('click')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that using the **right version of phantomjs** is fundamental.

Although 2.x is out, I noticed that **phantomjs 1.8.2** behaves much more as expected and is way less buggy.

I'm currently testing autocompleted fields in RailsAdmin with success **without using any delay technique**.

```
def fill_in_autocomplete(selector, text)
  find(selector).native.send_keys(*text.chars)
end

def choose_autocomplete_entry(text)
  find('ul.ui-autocomplete').should have_content(text)
  page.execute_script("$('.ui-menu-item:contains(\"#{text}\")').find('a').trigger('mouseenter').click()")
end
```

An example selector for **fill_in_autocomplete** would be:

```
".author_field .ui-autocomplete-input"
```