# Understanding native and send_keys in Capybara

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I am trying to understand the meaning of the following Capybara syntax. What exactly does `native` do? What is `send_keys` used for? Also, I would like to understand what this particular block does.

```
within('#step-3') do
 recipe_name = first(:xpath, '//*[@id="recipe-name"]').native
 recipe_name.clear
 recipe_name.send_keys('Email recipe')
end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Capybara uses a driver to control a browser or browser simulator (Rack::Test, Poltergeist, Selenium, etc.). Each driver must implement the API that Capybara defines. That API includes the Element class and its `.native` method. `.native` returns the object that the driver uses internally to represent a DOM element. Capybara itself doesn't have any use for that object, but some drivers' implementations of that object have driver-specific methods that can be useful in tests.

`.clear` and `.send_keys` are, then, driver-specific methods on the DOM element whose CSS selector is `#recipe-name`. Presumably it is an element that the user types into. We can probably guess what `.clear` does. `.send_keys` tells the element that the user has pressed each of the keys in the given string in order.

The point of using `.send_keys` rather than just doing `fill_in '#recipe-name' with: 'Email recipe'` is that some browser behavior, such as Javascript events, only happens when the user presses a key. Apparently `fill_in` puts text into the element in a way that doesn't make the browser think that any keys have been pressed. So if you're testing something that cares about keypress events, you need to use `.send_keys`.

I gave an example of using `.send_keys` in [my answer to a question about testing a jQuery autocomplete field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23378110/634576).

Comment: I am rescuing the clear, since it is necessary in Firefox and is not defined in poltergeist...