# Capybara: How to fill a textarea without an 'id'?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, capybara

I am in need to `fill_in` a textarea which does not have an `id`. Following the inspection:

```
<textarea class="stock-description-input js-short-description-textarea" placeholder="Select a product or enter a description" maxlength="64"></textarea>
```

Have you got an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different location techniques and ways to get to the desired element. `stock-description-input` class looks like a good thing to rely on. [Use `send_keys()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25701162/771848) to fill the area:

```
text_area = first(:css, 'textarea.stock-description-input').native
text_area.send_keys('Test')
```

Comment: This is cool. I've read thanks to you something about native and send_keys. In case I wished to retrieve the information sent, is there the equivalent for find("id").value?

Comment: Thanks!! - first(:css, 'textarea.stock-description-input').value