# JQuery AutoComplete, manually trigger select callback with custom data

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a way i can manually trigger the `select` and pass custom `data` into it?
I look into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242669/jquery-autocomplete-manually-select-first-searched-item-and-bind-click/15466735#15466735), but this just automate the ui and `click` on the dropdown item.
My jQuery autocomplete initialization is look like this:

```
$("#id_full_name").autocomplete({
    source: "/messages/fax/contact_autocomplete/",
    minLength: 1,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
    },
    select: function(event, data) {
        if (true) {
            /* Do something */
        } else {
            /* Do something */
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare an actual function and call the function as needed:

```js
function select(event, data) {
  // ... whatever code
}
$("#id_full_name").autocomplete({
    source: "/messages/fax/contact_autocomplete/",
    minLength: 1,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
    },
    select: select
});
select(null, "custom data");
```

Comment: I develop chrome extension, have no access to the source code :)