# how can I set default text and value in jquery autocomplete and trigger select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an array of objects (assessorList), how can I set default text and value in the jquery autocomplete and trigger select. For example if I send second object from the array to the function then Assessor 2, Test should be selected with 1116512 in AutoCompleteAssessorID and all the statements under select should be executed for that selection.

My HTML:

```
<input style="width:300px" id="AutoCompleteAssessor"> <input type="hidden" id="AutoCompleteAssessorID">
```

My JavaScript:

```
var assessorList = [{ id:"1116542",  label:"Assessor 1, Test"}, { id:"1116512",  label:"Assessor 2, Test"}, { id:"1117290",  label:"Carey, Peter"}] 

function a(ID, Text)
{
    $("#AutoCompleteAssessor").autocomplete({ 
        autoFocus: true, 
        minLength: 3,
        source: assessorList,
        focus: function(event, ui){ 
            $("#AutoCompleteAssessor").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#AutoCompleteAssessorID").val(ui.item.id);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui){                        
            $("#AutoCompleteAssessor").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#AutoCompleteAssessorID").val(ui.item.id);

            userId = ui.item.id;            
            getEventData();                 
            return false;
        },
        change: function (event, ui){
            if(!ui.item)
            { 
                $("#AutoCompleteAssessor").val('');
                $("#AutoCompleteAssessorID").val('');               
            }
        }
    })  
}
```

I tried $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._trigger('select', 'autocompleteselect', {item:{value:$(this).val()}}); but i get $(...).data(...) is undefined error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you trigger autocomplete "select" event manually in jQueryUI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633727/how-do-you-trigger-autocomplete-select-event-manually-in-jqueryui)

Comment: I tried $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._trigger('select', 'autocompleteselect', {item:{value:$(this).val()}}); but I get $(...).data(...) is undefined error.