# Replace function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I want replace "İ" character to "i". This code works perfect without other jquery library in page. But it doesn't work with autocomplete script.

```
$k(document).ready(function(){   
    $k(".replace").on("keyup", function(){
        str = $k(this).val();
        var dizi = { "İ": "i" };
        str = str.replace(/(([İı]))+/g, function(harf){ return dizi[harf];     })
        $k(this).val(str);
    });   
});
```

Is there a way to solve it or any other code can use.

Thanks...

Comment: you mean if you hit a suggest

Comment: Can you create plunkr which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You're using `$` instead of `$k` in `.replace` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also trigger your function with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.replace').focusout(function(){
      str = $(this).val();
      var dizi = { "İ": "i" };
      str = str.replace(/(([İı]))+/g, function(harf){ return dizi[harf];});
      $(this).val(str);
   }).keyup(function() {
      str = $(this).val();
      var dizi = { "İ": "i" };
      str = str.replace(/(([İı]))+/g, function(harf){ return dizi[harf];});
      $(this).val(str);
   });
 });
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).delegate('.ac_even', 'click', function(){
        str = $('.replace').val();
        str = str.replace('İ', 'i'); 
        $('.replace').val(str);
    });
    $('.replace').focusout(function(){
      str = $(this).val();
      str = str.replace('İ', 'i');
      $(this).val(str);
   }).keyup(function() {
      str = $(this).val();
      str = str.replace("İ", "i");
      $(this).val(str);
   });
});
```

See:
[How do you trigger autocomplete "select" event manually in jQueryUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633727/how-do-you-trigger-autocomplete-select-event-manually-in-jqueryui)

so this will work if you focus out and if you hit something on the keyboard the Input/textarea and will do something.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I don't understand what i will do.

Comment: Your replace function will trigger if you hit some character or when you leave the input/textarea.

Comment: If i can, i will. I don't know where and what to write

Comment: Edited, are you turk? If yes I can talk to you how you do it in turkish. Tell me if this helped you.

Comment: Valla doğru diyorsun. Ama verdiğin kod çalışmadı. Autocomplete ile çakışıyor sanırım. Birini kaldırınca diğeri çalışıyor çünkü.

Comment: edem, sen bana o html kismini bana yolla. Ben yaparim o benden.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zokanzi/ga4rvr7h/ kodları buraya attım ama, asp sayfası olduğundan deneme nasıl yapacaksın. http://kirsehirilan.net/deneme.asp buradan da sorunu görebilirsin. Cari kısmına SELİM yazdığımda kayıt gelmiyor. IE'de sorun yok da chrome'da gelmiyor kayıtlar. O yüzden İ'yi küçültmem gerekiyor. Teşekkürler şimdiden.

Comment: abicim yukarida yaptigim gibi dogru .focusout yapinca zaaten cevirmesi gerek. Sen herhalte codu yanlis ekledin. Simdi benim yazdigimi ekle.

Comment: Abi yok ya. kirsehirilan.net/deneme.asp  adresine de ekledim. jquery sürümünden mi acaba anlamadım. Teşekkürler yine de, elinden geleni yaptın.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zokanzi/pmgo0qrt/ buraya attım da burada da çalışmadı. class olarak değil başka bir şey olarak mı vermem gerekiyor.

Comment: sitende jQuery okunmuyor

Comment: Ekledim ya. Nedeni ne ki. Bir de autocomplete nasıl çalışıyor jQuery okunmuyorsa.

Comment: jquery baska bir link kullandin

Comment: jsfiddle.net/zokanzi/pmgo0qrt  buradaki script niye çalışmıyor.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/zr36wnz9 buyur kocum hata bende, ben degistirdigimi geri inputa vermedigim icin böyle oldu kusura bakma kanka

Comment: Ya fiddle'daki çalışıyor da, benim sayfada çakışıyor birşeyle. Bulamadım valla.

Comment: Sayfanin linkini bi paylasabilirmisin?